# Assistance in Improving a query's performace

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, query-optimization, query-performance

**Overview**:

I have a system that builds the query statements. Some of which must join some tables to others based on set parameters passed into the system. When running some performance tests on the queries created I noticed that some of the queries were doing FULL TABLE SCANS, which in many cases, from what I've read is not good for large tables.

**What I'm trying to do**:

```
1 - Remove the full table scans 
2 - Speed up the Query
3 - Find out if there is a more efficient query I can have the system build instead
```

**The Query**:

```
SELECT a.p_id_one, b.p_id_two, b.fk_id_one, c.fk_id_two, d.fk_id_two, 
d.id_three, d.fk_id_one 
FROM ATable a 
LEFT JOIN BTable b ON a.p_id_one = b.fk_id_one 
LEFT JOIN CTable c ON b.p_id_two = c.fk_id_two 
LEFT JOIN DTable d ON b.p_id_two = d.fk_id_two 
WHERE a.p_id_one = 1234567890
```

[**The Explain**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbpQh.png)

**Query Time**

```
Showing rows 0 - 10 (11 total, Query took 0.0016 seconds.)
```

**Current issues**:

1 - Query time for my system/DBMS (phpmyadmin) takes between 0.0013 seconds and 0.0017 seconds.

- What have I done to fix?
  The full table scans or 'ALL' type queries are being ran on tables ('BTable', 'DTable') so I've tried to use FORCE INDEX on the appropriate ids.
  Using FORCE INDEX removes the full table scans but it doesn't speed up the 
  performance.
  I double checked my fk_constraints and index relationships to ensure I'm not missing anything. So far everything checks out.

2 - Advisor shows multiple warnings a few relate back to the full table scans and the indexes.

**Question(s)**:

Assume all indexes are available and created

1 - Is there a better way to perform this query?

2 - How many joins are too many joins?

3 - Could the joins be the problem?

4 - Does the issue rest within the WHERE clause?

5 - What optimize technique/tool could I have missed?

6 - How can I get this query to perform at a speed between 0.0008 and 0.0001?

If images and visuals are needed to help clarify my situation please do ask in a comment below. I appreciate any and all assistance.

Thank you =)

Comment: I don't think there is better alternative for the query

Comment: Please post an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) output.

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN into the question, Please review thank you.

Comment: If 0.0017s is too slow for you, there must be more to this issue than just this query. Please give context for the overall problem you are trying to solve, so we can understand why you need this query to be below 0.001s. Most likely we will be better able to help with the overall problem, rather than trying to squeeze this already super fast query down even more.

Comment: I'll dive deeper into any missing contextual pieces I could be missing in this question and post in an edited update.

Answer (score 1):

"p_id_one" does not tell us much.  Is this an auto_increment?  Real column names sometimes gives important clues of cardinality and intent.  As Willem said, "there must be more to this issue" and "what is the overall problem".

`LEFT` -- do you need it?  It prevents certain forms of optimizations; remove it if the 'right' table row is not optional.

`WHERE a.p_id_one = 1234567890` needs `INDEX(p_id_one)`.  Is that the `PRIMARY KEY` already?  In that case, an extra `INDEX` is not needed.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Are those really the columns/expressions you are `SELECTing`?  It *can* make a difference -- especially when suggesting a "covering index" as an optimization.

Please provide the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  (That is not the discussion you did provide.)  That output would help with clues of 1:many, cardinality, etc.

If these are `FOREIGN KEYs`, you already have indexes on b.fk_id_one, c.fk_id_two, d.fk_id_two; so that is nothing more to do there.

1.6ms is an excellent time for a query involving 4 tables.  Don't plan on speeding it up significantly.  You probably handle hundreds of connections doing thousands of similar queries per second.  Do you need more than that?

Are you using InnoDB?  That is better at concurrent access.

Your example does not *seem* to have any full table scans; please provide an example that does.

`ALL` on a 10-row table is nothing to worry about.  On a million-row table it is a big deal.  Will your tables grow significantly?  You should note this when worrying about `ALL`:  A full table scan is sometimes *faster* than using the 'perfect' index.  The optimizer decide on the scan when the estimated number of rows is more than about 20% of the table.  A table scan is efficient because it is scanning straight through the table, even if skipping 80% of the rows.  Using an index is more complex -- the index is scanned, but for each row found in the index, a lookup is needed into the data to find the row.  If you see `ALL` when you don't think you should, then *probably* the index is not very selective.  Don't worry.

Don't use `FORCE INDEX` -- although it may help the query with today's values, it may hurt tomorrow's query.

Comment: The columns being selected are not the actual columns. They are dummy fields meant to give a general idea as to what I'm working with. However the SQL and the EXPLAIN are close in resemblance to the actual query. 
The EXPLAIN is a link to an image of the explain. As my reputation on stackoverflow is not at 15 I cannot post actual images on here. p_id_one is a primary id key as fk_id_one is a foreign key.
Though people are saying 1.6ms is very good I'm only looking to see if a better solution is possible at all.
InnoDB? of course. Full table scans was removed via FORCE INDEX.

Comment: The tables will grow significantly so I need my database to be as quick as possible now with the intent on it being kept that way as time goes on.

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Perhaps the tables are so small, that the full scan versus using the index may go away with size.  The `EXPLAIN` says that the things are working well.  You _may_ be having unnecessary worries.

Comment: Currently each table has 0 rows. However, running a bench test with a similar query where 30,000 dummy rows are inserted show that the query time doesn't change much. I'll run a bench test on what I have with 100,000 rows in each table and see how it works and post my results to see if any fine tuning and tweaks need to be made. As you said, today's query might hurt tomorrow's query. so why not dry run it to find out on dummy data.

Comment: Keep in mind when benchmarking that the first run is likely to be slower because of caching.  0 rows is pretty useless for timing.  30K and 100K will probably be similar.  Is it 1.6ms for 30K rows?  Is that the only interesting query?

Comment: Apologies for the response delay, work has had me swamped. To answer your question, no... not yet at least. Currently I'm still building out the system that builds these queries and I'm doing so with as much DBA know-how as possible. For the moment a heavy benchmarking has yet to take place as I am only aming to stomp any possible problems I feel may be an issue now and find if there could be other discrepancies I may be overlooking in the process. Other queries would involve functions, number crunching, and probabilities as the system and DB advance even more.